# How to conduct a load-test for a ZooKeeper Cluster by using Apache JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to conduct load-tests for a ZooKeeper cluster of 5 computers that I configured. I checked that the nodes in the cluster are working properly, but didn't know how to prepare a `Test Plan` in Apache JMeter.

I don't know if it is possible to use a default sampler such as `HTTP Sampler` or `Java Request` or something else. Therefore, I looked for a plugin specific for Apache ZooKeeper, however could not find any.

So my question is are there any way to run a load-test on a ZooKeeper Cluster by using Apache JMeter? If not, what other tools would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There is [A series of tools for ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.8.0/zookeeperTools.html) page which has [Benchmark](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.8.0/zookeeperTools.html#Benchmark) sub-page which in its turn suggests using the following:

- [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB)
- [zk-smoketest](https://github.com/phunt/zk-smoketest)
- [Byteman](https://byteman.jboss.org/)
- [jepsen](https://github.com/jepsen-io/jepsen)

apart from the above there is [ZooKeeper Benchmark](https://github.com/brownsys/zookeeper-benchmark)

Those which are Java-based can be used from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or you can create your own Java Request Sampler or [your own implementation of a ZooKeeper JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development).